# Fully connected subgraphs - what is it called and what is an efficient way of finding one?

Tags: graph-theory

By 'fully connected subgraph' I mean two (not necessarily complete) subgraphs, where each node in one is connected/mapped to each node in the other.

I have not been able to find a name for this - it is a bit like a clique. Is there a name for it?

I have a starting set of nodes, and I would like to find the the other set which are fully mapped to the starting set. There are enough nodes to make me want to do this in an efficient way. Is there a way other than the brute force method of taking all the neighbours connected to the starting set and doing an intersection?
(I suspect not)

Background: This is a property graph (Titan) and the nodes are different types, but I don't think this affects the question.

Comment: Ok, I really did look before posting, but found this about 30 seconds after posting [Turán graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tur%C3%A1n_graph).

I'll read up a bit to see if there is a simple way of finding them...

Comment: It is not quite the the right name/thing, since the sizes are not necessary close to equal and we are looking for a subgraph in a larger graph.

Comment: Ok, I think this is what the thing is called [Complete bipartite graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_bipartite_graph) or biclique.


Now I just need to find one given the the starting set.

Comment: "each node in one is connected/mapped to each node in the other" - This is exactly what I am looking for.    

"no other connection exists with other node not part of the sub graphs" - No, each of the two node sets is connected to nodes in a much bigger graph, with multiple edge types. I have one set, and I want to find its biclique.

Comment: [This](http://bmcbioinformatics.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1471-2105-15-110) looks like an interesting paper. It does what I want, I think, but I just want to find one of them.